# Como importar datos de un DataGridView a un documento Excel sin librerias? c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, datagridview

Estoy un poco desorientado,me gustaria una sugerencia alternativa de librerias para poder importar datos a un documento excel

> O tambien si existe una libreria facil de usar que me recomienden estaria perfecto

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es mediante OleDB:

Conexión para xls

```
szConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" +
PathDelExcel + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
```

Conexión para xlsx

```
szConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + 
PathDelExcel + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
```

Para escribir

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = @"Insert into [Hoja1$] (month,mango,apple,orange) 
        VALUES ('DEC','40','60','80');";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //exception here
    }
    finally
    {
         conn.Close();
         conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

En [este enlace](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/9014/read-write-excel-file-with-oledb-in-c-without-interop) encontrarás el código completo para el `insert` y el `update`. No es posible hacer `delete`.

Por otra parte, trabajar con una librería como [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) es mucho más flexible. Y además es sencilla de utilizar. [Aquí tienes muchos ejemplos](https://riptutorial.com/epplus).

Answer (score 1):

Si el archivo des formato .xlsx puedes intentar descomprimirlo como si se tratara de un zip (por que realmente lo es) y explorar el contenido, allí dentro encontraras todo lo que define el archivo de Excel, en este, hay un directorio llamado "worksheets" en el cual podrás ubicar un XML por cada hoja que este tenga y deserializando esta hoja accedes tanto a la data del Excel así como a las formulas y demás.

No te recomiendo hacer esto, mas bien utiliza una librería que haga todo esto por ti, dado que hay muchas. Pero si en realidad no quieres o puedes utilizar libreras (NuGet), entonces intenta este proceso como te indico.

Por otra parte si el archivo es formato .xls eso es una caja negra y necesariamente te tocara cargar una referencia COM teniendo Office instalado en el equipo para poder intentar extraer el contenido.

Espero te sirva de algo, saludos.

Comment: Me sirvio de mucho amigo, muchas gracias!

Comment: La opción OleDB también es posible, pero su implementación puede ser un dolor de cabeza, ya que por lo menos debes tener instalado del access database engine (ACE) para abrir XSLX y el Jet para abrir XLS, pero la cosa se pone fea cuando el bitness del SO y/o del Office y/o del access database engine comienzan a diferir, pues no existe el proveedor OleDb Jet para 64bits, es decir debes trabajar 100% a 32bits, pero puede que el ACE / Office este instalado 64bits, lo que supone otro problema, instalar los 2 entornos no te permite el mismisimo Office. Bienvenido al dolor de cabeza.